# docker-compose.yml file behaves differently on ECS than local docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I have the following minimal docker-compose.yml:

```
worker:
  working_dir: /app
  image: <my-repo>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ocean-boiler:latest
  cpu_shares: 4096
  mem_limit: 524288000
  command: /bin/bash -c "bin/delayed-job --pool=*:1"
```

When  I run it locally it using docker-compose, love and happiness.

When I request ECS runs it remotely, I get the following:

`ecs-cli up`

=>

`time="2016-05-03T11:40:00-07:00" level=info msg="Stopped container..." container="<cid-redacted>/worker" desiredStatus=STOPPED lastStatus=STOPPED taskDefinition="ecscompose-spud:73"`

then; we check the fallout using ps:

`ecs-cli ps`

=>

`<cid-redacted>/worker  STOPPED Reason: DockerStateError: [8] System error: exec: "/bin/bash -c \"bin/delayed-job --pool=*:1\"": stat /bin/bash -c "bin/delayed-job --pool=*:1": no such file or directory      ecscompose-spud:73`

I've been down the rabbit hole of not referring to any files without complete paths. My docker instance functions as intended whether I run it locally or on a remote machine, however ordering it about with ecs-cli seems to be sad-panda business.

Just running it locally with `docker-compose up` functions as intended... Any halp would be appreciated!

EDIT: Finally fixed. Using `command:` categorically worked *super* bad for me - my docker containers now contain the command needed to run; and my advice is to avoid the use of command unless you really need it.